Configurar pusher en Laravel 11
Hellos comunidad, fíjense que quiero usar pusher para hacer la gestión de notificaciones en una aplicación Laravel 11, y e intentado seguir el ejemplo que da la web y sigo los paso pero al momento de enviar el event desde PHP no llega hasta la vista, y si hago una prueba desde la web si me llega correctamente, entonces queria saber si podrian guiarme a configurar bien los archivos necesarios para comunicar mi backend con mi frontend
mi brocasting.php esta asi:
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'us2',
                'useTLS' => true
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

y mi .env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=ID
PUSHER_APP_KEY=KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET= SECRET

y lo recibo desde el welcome que genera Laravel:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/8.2.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('1a1cfb67c6038dc24cc7', {
      cluster: 'us2'
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
  </p>
</body>


y desde un controller de prueba ejecuto esto:
     public function index(){
        event(new MyEvent("Hola Mundo"));
        return "Enviado";
    }

Les agradezco mucho su tiempo
